# How can I update a directive when a service finishes loading in a controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive

In an AngularJS app, I have a service that uses `$http` and returns a promise. I have a controller which requires the service. In the controller `DataService.then(function(data){ scope.viewModel.data = data;})`

Then I have a directive with isolate scope.
`scope: { data: '='}` then do something with scope.data inside the directive.

Finally the html

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div my-cool-directive="" data="viewModel.data"></div>
</div>
```

My question is this presents a chicken before the egg scenario. When the service data is hard coded, all is well and glorious, however when using async `$http` to actually call a server and get data, scope.data is null inside the directive. How can I properly get the directive the data it needs when the service call finishes and the controller scope property is set. I do not want the directive to have a dependency on the service. I prefer that the controller will drive the directive model. Is `$emit` or `$broadcast` the way to go and use a `$watch`? Basically eventing? or is there a preferred way to do this? I'm certain others have faced this exact issue. I would like the directive to continue to have isolate scope as I may want to extend at some point. I did try to Google first but I don't think I was phrasing the question correctly.

Comment: try, `DataService.then(function(data){ $timeout(function(){scope.viewModel.data = data;}}));`, I'll explain what's happening if it works.

Comment: It is not guaranteed to work, and why is there a timeout there... One way is to do with watch, or use a Pub/Sub mechanism. I personally do not like eventing though.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div my-cool-directive="" data="viewModel.data" ng-if="viewModel.data"></div>
```

should do the trick.

You could also create a watch in the directive, so that the callback function of the watch is called when the data changes from undefined to something else.

Comment: This solution actually works well for me. The directive is not even rendered until that data comes into scope [no pun intended]. I like it. Clean and simple.